# Convert Childobject to array

Tags: javascript

i have parsed a json object in javascript.
Inside this Json i have a childnode which i want to be an array.

I have this:

```
{
   "orders":{
      "id":"1206435",
      "version":"1.12",
      "senderId":"81",
      "orders":[
         {
            "id":"5044534",
            "header":{
               "orderDate":"20220922",
               "reference":"11152627",
               "address":{
                  "name":"123",
                  "address1":null,
                  "address2":null,
                  "address3":"123",
                  "postalCode":"71696",
                  "city":"123",
                  "country":"123"
               },
               "mannerOfTransport":"360"
            },
            "details":{
               "line":{
                  "id":"2",
                  "item":"74015775",
                  "supplieritem":"381920",
                  "needbydate":"2022/09/22 07:08:18"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But what i need is to convert the details part to be an array like this:

```
{
   "orders":{
      "id":"1206435",
      "version":"1.12",
      "senderId":"81",
      "orders":[
         {
            "id":"5044534",
            "header":{
               "orderDate":"20220922",
               "reference":"11152627",
               "address":{
                  "name":"123",
                  "address1":null,
                  "address2":null,
                  "address3":"123",
                  "postalCode":"71696",
                  "city":"123",
                  "country":"123"
               },
               "mannerOfTransport":"360"
            },
            "details":[{
               "line":{
                  "id":"2",
                  "item":"74015775",
                  "supplieritem":"381920",
                  "needbydate":"2022/09/22 07:08:18"
               }
            }]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If i do this:

```
let result = Object.entries(OrderFile.orders.orders[0].details).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }));
```

I get the details part back as an expected array but how can i change/modify the origin part?
I need the entire object not just the "result".

I hope thats clear somehow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild the data object by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an updated order object where each object's details are placed in an array.

```js
const data={orders:{id:"1206435",version:"1.12",senderId:"81",orders:[{id:"5044534",header:{orderDate:"20220922",reference:"11152627",address:{name:"123",address1:null,address2:null,address3:"123",postalCode:"71696",city:"123",country:"123"},mannerOfTransport:"360"},details:{line:{id:"2",item:"74015775",supplieritem:"381920",needbydate:"2022/09/22 07:08:18"}}}]}};

const out = {
   ...data,
  orders: {
    ...data.orders,
    orders: data.orders.orders.map(order => {
      return { ...order, details: [ order.details ] };
    })
  }
};

console.log(out);
```